# PhpStorm xdebug can't find file when connection comes from docker container

Tags: docker, phpstorm, docker-compose, xdebug

I'm trying to move my Magento development environment to docker. I've started with [this](https://github.com/arvatoSCM/dockerize-magento2) ready to use solution. Almost everything works properly except xdebug.

I've set up PhpStorm according to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@pablofmorales/xdebug-with-docker-and-phpstorm-786da0d0fad2) and I have properly mapped my local project directory on docker volume in the server section. When I try to start debugging then appears in debugger window this message

> Cannot find file '/var/www/html/pub/index.php' locally.
>   To fix it set server name by environment variable PHP_IDE_CONFIG and restart debug session.

I've added this

```
environment:
  - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=Magetwo
```

to the `docker-compose.yml` in the php section, but still the same error. Debugging works only when I have project located in the same directory on the host like in the container volume, but I want to have different directory.

What should I change to force xdebug to work?

Comment: Not a Docker user .. but accordingly to that manual should it be something like `PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Magento"` instead (I'm referring to the syntax differences)?

Comment: how about `XDEBUG_CONFIG: 'idekey=PHPSTORM'`

Answer (score 15):

The same issue applies, when trying to debug on PHPStorm with docker.

You can resolve it by adding a `server_name` to the nginx config :

The `server_name  _;` should get set to `_`, which is the default server name. You can also add **another** server name, resulting in PhpStorm adding a new PHP Server (Settings: PHP > Servers) and will use this as the `Name`: `server_name  _  MyProject;`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ### Add the following line to nginx config file ###
    server_name  _  AnotherServerNameForPhpStorm;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app_bug:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include xdebug/remote.conf;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone still has the same problem with me

Comment: You should highlight what exact part of your sample code solves the issue

Comment: Thank you! This answer should be accepted - this solved it for me.

Comment: Why does this work? I sweat XDebug is like black magic sometimes...

Comment: server_name _;// add this line to nginx config file
this line let nginx accept any domain

Comment: sweet, this fixed my issue

Answer (score 12):

I usually set the docker subnet IP as a remote host ip like this:

```
XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=172.17.0.1
PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=your_server_name_in_phpstorm_settings
```

You could check ip in Linux with this command:

```
ifconfig docker0
```

Also if you're using docker-compose you could move xdebug variables definitions to a separate .env file and link it to the container config in docker-compose.yml:

```
container_name:
    ...
    env_file: .env
    ...
...
```

Comment: You can also use `XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=host.docker.internal` on windows (haven't tried other OS, but it should [work](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host), instead of hard-coding your machine's IP.

Comment: docker.for.mac.host.internal for MacOS

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this way:

```
environment:
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Magetwo"
```

Then in Settings > PHP > Servers add a new server with name `Magetwo`and the host and port you're using to debug.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced with same problem
Try to add in xdebug config this line:

```
xdebug.extended_info = 1
```

it should to pass env variable to $_SERVER

Comment: In Xdebug 3, it appears this setting is [no longer available](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#removed-xdebug.extended_info)

Answer (score 2):

Please, inside docker-compose.yaml add this code for yours application container

```
environment:
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=name_of_yours_host_in_phpstorm"
  XDEBUG_CONFIG: "idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

Example:

```
environment:
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=localhost"
```

Additionally. xdebug settings in php.ini file:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable = On
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=yes
xdebug.log="/path/in/your/project/to/xdebug.log"
```

and inside docker-compose.yaml add this code for yours application container

```
    volumes:
  - ./path/in/your/project/to/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

`It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, same 'To fix it set server name by environment variable PHP_IDE_CONFIG and restart debug session.'

What solved it for me ultimately was having $_ENV['PHP_IDE_CONFIG'] set. Check your $_ENV when you get this message, I bet you won't have a key called 'PHP_IDE_CONFIG'.

How do we get this set?
First make sure that you have an environment variable called PHP_IDE_CONFIG in your container. If you don't then get that set. I personally use a file to define my env variables. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers and search for 'env_file'.

Once you get your env variables into your container, and it's still not working, then try this:
Go to View > Tool Windows > Docker. Then click Edit Configurations (it's an icon). In there, make sure you are connected to Docker and you have a mapping of your vm path to your local path.

In addition to this, I used Oleg's answer to set

`xdebug.extended_info=1`
 
Although this in and of itself did not fix the issue for me, I am using this setting.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue for incorrect mappings. In my case, I am using Laravel in a docker container from a standard PHP image. XDebug is installed and enabled in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \  
&& docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

And the config I use for Debug is:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.extended_info = 1
```

The important point I was missing is the fact that Laravel's starting point is in Public/index.php, and this mapped automatically, whereas the project root needs to be manually mapped. To do this, go to PHP Storm settings, in the PHP section, open the Debug section and add a server (it might be already added automatically). Make sure the port is set correctly too. Then in the mapping section, in front of the project route path, add the absolute path on your machine.

As well worth mentioning that in case you want to see what XDebug is saying in diagnostics logs, you can use the following function in your PHP code:

```
xdebug_info();
```